# sonar runner showing http://localhost:9000 can not be reached

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am facing the issue after successful installing sonarqube and sonar runner. 
When I run in project /sonar-runner it is showing error.
Anyone can help ?

```
ERROR: Sonar server 'http://localhost:9000' can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.109s
Final Memory: 0M/87M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1392)
at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.ok(HttpRequest.java:1417)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:93) at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:47)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.version(ServerVersion.java:38)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.is37Compatible(ServerVersion.java:58)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:36) at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)  at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)  at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1548) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1544) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1542) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1193) at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:397) at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1390) ... 15 more
```

Below mention sonar log is:

```
    --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.App: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
  java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]

Where:
  app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
  app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
                  application.
```

Comment: It seems that this is a jenkins error/console log. If so check if you have configured `sonar-runner plugin` correctly,  check if you have uncommented `conf` file from `sonar-runner` also.

Comment: I have enabled conf/sonar.properties and /sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties.

Comment: Can you check if sonar is working locally(`localhost:8080`)? Also giving more details about what sonar version and os are you using, how you configured(you included a `sonar-project.properties` file or configured on `jenkins`), etc maybe can help us figure out.

Comment: No sonar-runner is not working locally and sonar version is 5.1.2.

Comment: can you post the `conf/sonar.log` stacktrace?

Comment: Sonar runner log: 
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.App: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
  java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]
Where: app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the application.

Comment: Please edit your question with these logs and more details, as comment section is character limited

Comment: It seems main problem is " Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"  What java version you are using , SonarQube 5.x needs java 7+ ,

Comment: I am using Java verion is 1.6.0_36.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Is it solved ?  anyone find solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i have replaced the  sonar.host.url=http://10.xxx.XX.30:9000

Answer (score 0):

The **java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError** issue happens when you try to run program class files created using higher Java version into lower Java version. To resolve this issue follow these steps:

1. Go to /opt/sonar/sonarqube-6.7.3/conf
2. Edit below line in wrapper.conf file and restart sonar.
   `wrapper.java.command=/My/jdk_home/bin/java`